# Bootstrap doesn't work in my Rails app with mongodb

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter-bootstrap, mongodb

I have a simple Rails app with mongodb as my database.
I just want to add bootstrap to it and previously I didn't have any problems with this, but this time I have.

**Gemfile**

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
gem 'rails', '4.2.6'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
gem 'bootstrap-sass'
gem 'sprockets-rails'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.1.0'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'turbolinks'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0', group: :doc
gem 'mongoid'
```

So, I've added **bootstrap-sass**

Here I include it in my **application.js**

```
//= require jquery
//= require bootstrap-sprockets
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .
```

And here in **application.scss**

```
/*
 *= require_self
 *= require_tree .
*/
@import "bootstrap-sprockets";
@import "bootstrap";
```

**development.rb**

```
Mongoid.load!("config/mongoid.yml", :development)
```

**mongoid.yml**

```
development:
  clients:
    default: 
      database: app
      hosts:
        - localhost:27017
      options:

  options:
test:
  clients:
    default:
      database: app_test
      hosts:
        - localhost:27017
      options:
        read:
          mode: :primary
        max_pool_size: 1
```

It doesn't work. Moreover, when a try to write something like

```
<body>
  <h1>test</h1>
  <%= yield %>
</body>
```

in my **application.html.erb**  doesn't display on the page.

Comment: What is output? Some error, blank screen?

Comment: The standart output like Started GET controller etc. But no changes in the interface and no errors.

Comment: In what environment do you run your app (`development` vs. `production`), did you try to run `rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=production`? Does that work without errors? Are there errors in your log file?

Comment: I run rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=development and got (rake aborted!
Mongoid::Errors::NoEnvironment: 
message:
  Could not load the configuration since no environment was defined.
summary:
  Mongoid attempted to find the appropriate environment but no Rails.env, Sinatra::Base.environment, RACK_ENV, or MONGOID_ENV could be found.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that in my controller I wrote

```
class BotsController < ActionController::Base
```

Now changed to

```
class BotsController < ApplicationController
```

and it works.